# Centos Stream 9: ImportError when running 'yum' due to undefined symbol 'SSL_CTX_set_srp_password'

Tags: centos

I'm a newbie, i'm testing on Centos Stream 9 and i got the trouble with yum command, when i ran the yum command, i receive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 61, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libdnf.transaction
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import conf
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/conf.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _conf
ImportError: /lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_set_srp_password, version OPENSSL_1.0.1
```

Do you have any solution to fix this trouble?
Thanks all!

Can not run yum command in centos stream 9